# How to disable Google Now Cards?

Tags: google-now

I find Google Now Cards annoying. How may I disable them?

Answer (score 5):

Open Google app.
Go to *Settings > Now Cards*

Disable both *Show all cards* and *Notifications*.

This should solve the problem.